# Confused about binding the enter key in tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

This is a search bar program and once enter is hit it will open google with whatever I searched:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import webbrowser

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Search Bar")

label1 = ttk.Label(root, text="Query")
label1.grid(row=0, column=0)
entry1 = ttk.Entry(root, width=50)
entry1.grid(row=0, column=1)


def callback():
    webbrowser.open("http://google.com/search?q="+entry1.get())


def get(event):
    webbrowser.open("http://google.com/search?q=" + entry1.get())


button1 = ttk.Button(root, text="Search", width=10, command=callback)
button1.grid(row=0, column=2)

entry1.bind("<Return>", get)

root.mainloop()
```

What I'm most confused about is why did I need a second function [get(event)] in order to bind the enter key at `entry1.bind("<Return>", get)`. Why couldn't I just put `entry1.bind("<Return>", callback)` (which is for the button). For some reason, the enter bind function requires a parameter and I'd just like an explanation as to why that is? Even though whatever is in the parameter is not being called.

Comment: you can use `def callback(event=None):` and then you can use with `command=` and `bind()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `event=None` in

```
def callback(event=None):
```

and then you can use with `command=` and `bind()`

`bind()` will run it with `event`, `command=` will run it without event and it will use `None`

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import webbrowser

def callback(event=None):
    webbrowser.open("http://google.com/search?q="+entry1.get())

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Search Bar")

label1 = ttk.Label(root, text="Query")
label1.grid(row=0, column=0)

entry1 = ttk.Entry(root, width=50)
entry1.grid(row=0, column=1)

button1 = ttk.Button(root, text="Search", width=10, command=callback)
button1.grid(row=0, column=2)

entry1.bind("<Return>", callback)

root.mainloop()
```

`bind()` can be used with different events and objects so it send this information to function - ie. `event.widget` - so you can bind the same function to different objects.

```
def callback(event=None):
    print(event)
    if event: # if not None
        print(event.widget)
```

Comment: Ah I see now thank you for clarifying this is really helpful

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
def callback(event=None):
```

Or u can pass None as parameter

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import webbrowser

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Search Bar")

label1 = ttk.Label(root, text="Query")
label1.grid(row=0, column=0)
entry1 = ttk.Entry(root, width=50)
entry1.grid(row=0, column=1)


def callback():
    webbrowser.open("http://google.com/search?q="+entry1.get())


def get(event):
    webbrowser.open("http://google.com/search?q=" + entry1.get())


button1 = ttk.Button(root, text="Search", width=10, command=lambda x=None:get(x))
button1.grid(row=0, column=2)

entry1.bind("<Return>", get)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: So you don't need two functions at all.